# Conversion of SQL Left Outer Join Query to JPA Criteria

Tags: java, jpa

I have the following native SQL query that I am trying to convert to JPA criteria:

```
select et.* from t_empl_tx et, t_dept d 
where et.assigned_dept = d.dept (+)
  and et.employee_id = :employee_id
  and (et.start_date >= d.dept_est_date and
       et.start_date <= d.dept_close_date or
       et.start_date is null or
       d.dept is null)
```

(Note that (+) is roughly equivalent to a left outer join in this case. Yes, I know it denotes the OPTIONAL table, etc, etc).

Here is my attempt at the code:

```
EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<EmployeeTransaction> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(EmployeeTransaction.class);
Root<EmployeeTransaction> root = criteriaQuery.from(EmployeeTransaction.class);

    // this line bombs!
Join<EmployeeTransaction, Department> join = 
    root.join(EmployeeTransaction_.assignedDepartment).join(Department_.id).join(DepartmentCompositeId_.department, JoinType.LEFT);

List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(EmployeeTransaction_.id).get(EmployeeTransactionCompositeId_.employeeId), employeeId));
predicates.add(criteriaBuilder.or(
    criteriaBuilder.and(
    criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.<Date>get(EmployeeTransaction_.requestedStartDate), join.get(Department_.id).<Date>get(DepartmentCompositeId_.departmentCreationDate)),
    criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.<Date>get(EmployeeTransaction_.requestedStartDate), join.<Date>get(Department_.departmentCloseDate))
    ),
    criteriaBuilder.isNull(root.get(EmployeeTransaction_.requestedStartDate)),
    criteriaBuilder.isNull(join.get(Department_.id).get(DepartmentCompositeId_.departmentCreationDate))
));

criteriaQuery.select(root).where(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[]{}));

TypedQuery<EmployeeTransaction> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<EmployeeTransaction> result = query.getResultList();
```

This issue seems to be that I'm trying to join a string column, assigedDepartment, to a single field of a composite ID. This is perfectly legal in SQL, but not so easy in the code.

One option is to convert to a number of subqueries, which seems to kill the point of the left outer join entirely.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Jason

Comment: No time to write an answer but "select entity1 from entity1 left join entity1.field2 where ...". If you want the left join to be eagerly fetch you need to have "left join fetch".

Comment: The JoinType attribute only has three possible values: INNER, LEFT, and RIGHT. There does not seem to be an option for left join fetch.

Also, there is something wrong with the join() line. Even though the join() returns a SingularAttribute<>, I can't seem to chain the commands like that.

Comment: In JPA Criteria query you are referencing a table `DepartmentCompositeId` that's not present in the SQL query. Please complete the information by adding the relevant parts of the definition of each entity

Comment: You are joining (linking) `t_empl_tx` and `t_dept` tables in both outer left join and inner join? Is the *SQL* works in the database client? I mean pure SQL, without JPA, etc. Maybe I'm missing something, but I see your criteria `or d.dept is null`- doesn't it cancel your left join?

Answer (score 3):

You should post your entities so that the answers can be more specific.

However, I'll give a try.

If I am right, you can rewrite the query:

```
select et.* 
from t_empl_tx et
    left join t_dept d on et.assigned_dept = d.dept
where 
    et.employee_id = :employee_id
    and (
        et.start_date >= d.dept_est_date 
        and et.start_date <= d.dept_close_date
        or et.start_date is null 
        or d.dept is null)
```

So, shortly, you have to move the `JoinType.LEFT` to `assignedDepartment` join:

```
EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<EmployeeTransaction> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(EmployeeTransaction.class);

Root<EmployeeTransaction> root = criteriaQuery.from(EmployeeTransaction.class);
Join<EmployeeTransaction, Department> department =  root.join(EmployeeTransaction_.assignedDepartment, JoinType.LEFT);
Path<Date> employeeTransactionRequestedStartDate = root.get(EmployeeTransaction_.requestedStartDate);
Path<DepartmentCompositeId> departmentId = department.get(Department_.id);
Path<Date> departmentCreationDate = departmentId.get(DepartmentCompositeId_.departmentCreationDate)
Path<Date> departmentCloseDate = departmentId.get(DepartmentCompositeId_.departmentCloseDate)

criteriaQuery.select(root).where(
    criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get(EmployeeTransaction_.id).get(EmployeeTransactionCompositeId_.employeeId), employeeId),
    criteriaBuilder.or(
        criteriaBuilder.and(
            criteriaBuilder.greaterThanOrEqualTo(employeeTransactionRequestedStartDate, departmentCreationDate)),
            criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(employeeTransactionRequestedStartDate, departmentCloseDate)
        ),
        criteriaBuilder.isNull(employeeTransactionRequestedStartDate),
        criteriaBuilder.isNull(departmentCreationDate)
    )
);

TypedQuery<EmployeeTransaction> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery);
List<EmployeeTransaction> result = query.getResultList();
```